# Close Win10 'Start Menu' if open using AHK?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

I've made a AHK script to keep an application open and focused as soon as Windows starts / logs in. I've since found though that WinActivate doesn't work in Windows 10 if the Start Menu is open. And apparently the last time "WinClose, Start Menu" worked was in WinXP.

Here's my code changed to use notepad so you can easily see what I'm trying to do (WinClose Start Menu step):

```
#WinActivateForce
FocusTimer = 3000                               ;Time spent between refocusing on window (in milliseconds)
APP_TITLE = Untitled - Notepad                  ;Title of application window
APP_EXE = C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe       ;Application executable filepath

Sleep, %FocusTimer%                             ;Allows time for Windows to login and run other startup processes
While(TRUE)                                     ;Infinite loop for program commands
{
    Run, %APP_EXE%                              ;Opens application
    Sleep, %FocusTimer%                         ;Allows time for previous action
    While WinExist(APP_TITLE)                   ;Infinite loop for while application window is available
    {
        WinClose, Start Menu                    ;Closes Start Menu if open so as not to interrupt WinActivate command 
        WinActivate, %APP_TITLE%                ;Commands focus on the application window
        WinWaitActive, %APP_TITLE%, , 0         ;Waits for application window to have focus
        Sleep, %FocusTimer%                     ;Wait timer before starting the loop again
    }
    Sleep, %FocusTimer%                         ;Allows clean-up time before starting the program commands again
}
```

I don't want to do anything drastic by disabling the Start Menu altogether. I just want to close it to remind the user that "this PC is only to run this application". It'll also alert the fact if randoms walk in and say "The Start Menu keeps closing???" If they want to interrupt the application then they have to manually pause the script via the system tray icon.

TIA

Comment: `Send, {Esc}` closes the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Start Menu's title is no longer "Start Menu". This seems to work for me:

```
WinClose ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow ahk_exe SearchUI.exe
WinClose ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow ahk_exe StartMenuExperienceHost.exe ; Suggested by 0x464e
```

It will also close search and Cortana.

Comment: It can also be `StartMenuExperienceHost.exe` if specific parts of the start menu are active, and the above wont close it. Would need to detect which one it is.

Comment: @D. Pardal, @0x464e, have you tried the above code? On my system the Start Menu only closes with **`Process Close, StartMenuExperienceHost.exe`**.

Comment: I tested all of those but only `WinClose ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow ahk_exe SearchUI.exe` seemed to work. I've included all of them in my code though as fail-safes.
Thanks!

Comment: @S.Hampton You don't need to choose only one. You can use the two lines, so that if the first doesn't work, the second might work.